# success_message in DeleteView not shown

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a DeleteView:

```
class LectureDelete(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
model = Lecture
success_message = "Die Veranstaltung wurde gelöscht"
success_url = '/'

def get_object(self):
    qs = super(LectureDelete, self).get_object()
    if self.request.user.has_perm('edit_lecture', qs):
        return qs
    else:
        raise exceptions.PermissionDenied
```

And in my template to which the success_url links, I have the following code, which works fine with other messages:

```
{% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
        <p class="alert alert-dismissable {% if message.tags %}alert-{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            {{ message }}
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

But the message is not shown. Am I missing something? What am I doing worng? Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21926) in the Django issue tracker should answer your question.

> `SuccessMessageMixin` hooks to `form_valid` which is not present on `DeleteView` to push its message to the user.

It also gives an alternative way which works for me:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Thing

class ThingDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Thing
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list')
    success_message = "Thing was deleted successfully."

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        return super(ThingDelete, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`SuccessMessageMixin` was not used in the delete-view (but I do use it for the Create and Update views).
Hopefully this will be improved in later versions of Django (see [issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21926) for more info).

Comment: If there is an exception in super().delete() - e.g. the object can't be deleted bc of a FK constraint - this will still display a success message, right? Is there a way to confirm delete was a success before generating the message?

Comment: @BrettThomas That's correct, if there's an exception raised in super().delete() it will still display a success message. If you switch it up and call super first then the exception will prevent the message from being stored.

Comment: Currently (Django 4.1.6), `delete` is never called, hook into `form_valid` instead.

Answer (score 18):

[The answer by Hel1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25325228/276451) is mostly correct, but doesn't offer a solution for displaying fields within the success message, like this:

```
success_message = "Session %(name)s was removed successfully"
```

Simply get the object to be deleted and format the string with the object's dictionary, like this:

```
class SessionDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Session
    success_url = reverse_lazy('session_home')
    success_message = "Session %(name)s was removed successfully"

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message % obj.__dict__)
        return super(SessionDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from django.contrib import messages

class LectureDelete( DeleteView):
    model = Lecture

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, "deleted successfully")
        return reverse("/")
```

Comment: This worked for me but on the last line after reverse I had to add an actual pattern name from urls.py or i'd get this error <Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name>

Answer (score 3):

If you want to overcome the exception problem as in [Brett Thomas's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822509/success-message-in-deleteview-not-shown/25325228#comment95233343_25325228), you can update [Tocino's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656041/7924687) in this way:

```
class SessionDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
model = Session
success_url = reverse_lazy('session_home')
success_message = "Session %(name)s was removed successfully"

def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    data_to_return = super(SessionDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    messages.success(self.request, self.success_message % obj.__dict__)
    return data_to_return
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Django 4.0.0 or above the `DeleteView` can be used together with `SuccessMessageMixin` as per this [Release Note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#generic-views)

So in the following example which deletes the a User, the success message is displayed on the account logout page after the User is deleted.

```py
class UserDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    success_message = _("Your account has been deleted")
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account_logout')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Something to watch out for when upgrading from older versions of Django to Django >= 4.0.0

As per the same [Release Note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#generic-views): *Custom delete logic in delete() handlers should be moved to form_valid()*. We has success messages in `delete` methods which stopped working after the Django 4.0.0 upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're using the [messages framework of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages) in your template but not in your view.

In your view, try adding your success message like this:

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.success(request, "Die Veranstaltung wurde gelöscht")
```

Comment: @magda is using the message framework in her view by using the [SuccessMessageMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views).