# Django's SuccessMessageMixin not working with DeleteView

Tags: python, django

Following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-messages-in-class-based-views, I'm trying to add a success message to a `DeleteView`:

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin


class SessionDelete(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Session
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:sessions')
    success_message = "Session %(id)s (%(session_type)s) was deleted successfully"
```

However, I've noticed this doesn't work in Django 1.11.9. I found this pull request, https://github.com/django/django/pull/5992, but it appears to have been closed due to inactivity. Do I understand correctly that success messages still don't work correctly with `DeleteView`s?

Comment: Stumbled upon this too. Looks like this bug still isn't resolved.
The answer here worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822509/success-message-in-deleteview-not-shown/42656041#42656041

Comment: Possible duplicate of [success\_message in DeleteView not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822509/success-message-in-deleteview-not-shown)

Comment: A fix for this looks to be finally coming in Django 4.0: https://github.com/django/django/pull/13362

Answer (score 1):

1. Import `from django.contrib import messages`
2. Use this as your view or transform it into a mixin.

```py
class SessionDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Session
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:sessions')
    success_message = "Session %(id)s (%(session_type)s) was deleted successfully"
    
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message, 'danger')

        return super(SessionDelete, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

3. You don't need the SuccessMessageMixin it is working fine now!